# Java Sockets: read/write stream in two different ways one by one

Tags: java, sockets, stream

About java.net.Socket and java.io.
The server wants to send messages to a client, first use ObjectOutputStream to write(read, for client) an object, and then use BufferedWriter to write(read, for client)。

I can make it if I use `ObjectXXXStream` only or `BufferedXXX` only, but can't use them together on one stream. What should I do?

server:

```
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
oos.writeObject(dc);
// oos.close();

bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));          

bw.write("hahaha");
bw.flush();

while(true){
    line=br.readLine();
    if(line != null){
        ExecuteInput(line);
    }
}
```

in client:

```
ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
XXX dc = (XXX) ois.readObject();
// ois.close();

String line;
while(true){
    try {
        // System.out.println("000000");
        line=br.readLine();
        // System.out.println("111111");
        if(line != null)
            System.out.println("aaaa "+line);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("222222");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: why not just pick the same one for both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the `ObjectOutputStream` for both write operations. You cannot have 2 different types of streams for one socket, so you'd choose the most functional.

Although, I would question if sending objects is actually needed. You could instead send the state of the object and an "opcode" specifying what should be done with that state. But I don't know the purpose of `dc`, so I couldn't confirm

Comment: I just find it lengthy to parse a set of data (I just want to transfer the data in dc to the client). It seems that I should use BufferedReader/Writer instead.

Comment: @nblintao I feel the bandwidth saved is worth it. If you aren't sending Objects, then yes, `BufferedReader`. If you are sending objects, you'd be looking for an `ObjectInputStream`, since `BufferedReader` doesn't have that functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can't use multiple streams/readers/writers on a socket when one or more of them is buffered, and both `BufferedWriter` and `ObjectOutputStream` are buffered.

Just use `ObjectOutputStream()` and either send everything as objects or else send the strings via `writeUTF()`, which means you have to read the strings with `readUTF().`